# converter Data typescript

Tags: typescript

Eu estou tendo um problema relativamente simples, mas não estou conseguindo achar uma solução:

preciso enviar um request para salvar uma Data no banco de dados(sqlServer), mas a data tem que estar no formato `(yyyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss).`
Meu objeto porém, passa da seguinte forma `(2010-4-4)`, logo, eu preciso que ele vire `2010-04-04 00:00:00`

eu usei o `new Date(p)` passando esta data como parâmetro, mas ele não reconhece este formato, e no final me retorna `NaN`

como posso resolver este problema? segue meu código atual

```
    public formatData(d) {

    let date    = new Date(d);
    console.log(date)

    var ano  = date.getFullYear();
    var mes  = '' + (date.getMonth() + 1);
    var dia  = '' + date.getDate();

    if (mes.length  < 2) mes  = '0' + mes;
    if (dia.length  < 2) dia  = '0' + dia;

    return [ano, dia, mes].join('-') + ' ' + ['00', '00', '00'].join(':');
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer, se passar a data 2010-4-4 por essa sua função não retorna NaN, nem se eu rodar um new Date() com o retorno dela, o erro está em outra parte do código que não está aqui?

Comment: Por que a tag TypeScript? Não seria a mesma coisa se usar JavaScript normalmente?